# Android : R8 codeshrink issues reported in crashlytics

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, crashlytics, android-r8

I have tried to debug this crash but couldn't get the exact cause, but this is happening across the app.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
       at fm.e.run(R8$$SyntheticClass:7)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:238)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7829)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:512)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:986)
```

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
       at oh.e.e(R8$$SyntheticClass:216)
       at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.b(LiveData.java:6)
       at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.c(LiveData.java:8)
       at androidx.lifecycle.t.j(MutableLiveData.java:4)
       at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData$a.run(LiveData.java:5)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:254)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8243)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:612)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
```

AGP : v7.2

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, it's hard to tell just from looking on those stack traces. I would probably start by checking the logic (generated by R8) inside `fm.e.run` and `oh.e.e`, and then search where those synthetic classes are being used. You can do that either by inspecting the APK inside Android Studio; or ideally, by using some third party decompile tool - i.e. jadx.

Comment: @AlexLipov I tried progaurd retrace but didn't get exact stack traces.

Comment: Performing retrace makes sense when the original class built from the source, but in this case both classes are synthetic/generated by R8. Again, I'd suggest using a decompile tool to see how the generated code looks like and to find where it is being used.

Comment: This looks like cases where R8 determine that an NPE will always be thrown, and an explicit `throw null` is inserted. Please open issues on the R8 bug tracker at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=326788.

Comment: What is the app.gradle config? Are you uploading all the mapping files to Crashlytics? https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=android